# How do you make an array range between numbers?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pseudocode

I want to make numbers range in an array.

For example (in pseudocode):

```
**StudentNames** [1:30]           <---- numbers from 1 to 30
```

How do you make an array range between numbers?

Comment: Use range: range(1,30+1)

Comment: Are you sure you really want a list of numbers from 1 to 30? It seems an odd choice for `StudentNames`.

Answer (score 0):

what you want is this:

```
studentNames = list(range(1,31))
```

So now you have a list like...

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, ... 30]
```

You can change the values to whatever you want for the students.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `StudentNames` is already an array with size `n`, `n` >= 30. You can do the following

```py
a = list(map(lambda x: x*0, range(35)))
print(a)
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

a[1:31] = range(1, 31)
print(a)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```